# MVVM Cross java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Mvx.MvxListView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I try to add a fragment with MvxListView and bindings. I'm using v4.0.0.0 beta2.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mvx.MvxListView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/accountlistitem"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AllAccounts;ItemClick OpenOverviewCommand" />
```

The fragment:

```
public class AccountListFragment : MvxFragment
{
    public new AccountListViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (AccountListViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.AccountListLayout, null);
    }
}
```

and how I load the fragment in the main activity:

```
var fragmenTransaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
fragmenTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.content_pane, accountListFragment);
fragmenTransaction.Commit();
```

Here the error message:

> 08-28 00:28:40.783 I/MonoDroid( 4281):    Suppressed:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Mvx.MvxListView 08-28 00:28:40.783
>   I/MonoDroid( 4281):       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>   08-28 00:28:40.783 I/MonoDroid( 4281):        at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781) 08-28
>   00:28:40.783 I/MonoDroid( 4281):      at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841) 08-28
>   00:28:40.783 I/MonoDroid( 4281):      at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504) 08-28
>   00:28:40.783 I/MonoDroid( 4281):      ... 29 more 08-28 00:28:40.783
>   I/MonoDroid( 4281):   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class
>   not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

The GitHub Repository can be found [here](https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyManager)

What do I miss? I checked it with another project that has a working MvxListView, but can't spot any difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the controls full name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/accountlistitem"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AllAccounts;ItemClick OpenOverviewCommand" />
```